# Which key do I use to zoom with Minecraft Optifine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard, minecraft-optifine

In Optifine (minecraft), I want to know how to zoom in. I have tried all f keys and I have tried looking at controls. Optifine is installed and is running.

Answer (score 7):

Default key: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (Although in some versions it's <kbd>c</kbd>)

If that doesn't work look for the option under **Options > Controls > Zoom**. Now you can see what key is bound for zooming. If you want to rebind it, click on the key next to the "Zoom" and press the key you want to rebind it to.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, for most new optifine users, in 1.8 the default key for running is in fact <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and optifine therefore makes the default key for zoom <kbd>C</kbd>. This is just if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is not working :).

Comment: Weird... for me the default key was "r". I was using 1.8 optifine running under forge.

Answer (score 1):

It's just <kbd>C</kbd>, or if it dosen't, work try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. If it still doesn't work, go to control settings and then to miscellaneous. Find zoom and change it to the key you want.

Answer (score 0):

You use the <kbd>C</kbd> key, and if that isn't working, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, if all else fails, go to settings, controls, and find the zoom setting, also, if your spring key is set as <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> they might not either work because their fighting each other for the control. So make sure the two controls aren't overlapping each other, you can tell because the button will be red in the control settings.

Answer (score -1):

Its c I have it I changed it to c! How to do this go to options, control, 
zoom and then  change by pressing the letter you want on the keyboard!!

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what version of Optifine you installed. If it's lower than 1.8, it will probably be Left-CTRL. But if it's installation was based on a certain version and you play on another, your keys might be messed up. The best option is to go to Settings, and Miscellaneous. Go to the Zoom option, and look at the key it's based on. If it's red, set it to another, as it means that it's also controlling another option.

Comment: This question was answered several years ago and does not provide any new information.

Answer (score -2):

Hold down the "Control" key. Profit.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>C</kbd> is the zoom in key, but you have to have Optifine.

Comment: Nope. That key is `Ctrl` in some cases. Your answer doesn't add anything new.

Answer (score -3):

If you are running the optifine forge version, the key you're looking for is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, if you are using vanilla optifine, it is <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: This adds nothing not already said.